# How can we include all the files owned by the user and shared with the user with Google Drive Picker API?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker, google-drive-picker

I am using the google drive picker API in my application, I used the exact example shown in this link https://developers.google.com/picker/docs. But for me the pickers is showing only a few files. My requirement is to show and select all the files that the user owns or is shared with the user.

The picker builder code I am using is:

```
function createPicker() {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
         picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Is there something I can add in this builder code so that the user who is authenticated can see the list of all the files which he has in his Google Drive irrespective of shared or owned?

Comment: Which scopes do you use?

Comment: @BesoKakulia I am now using auth/drive.file

Comment: Try to set all necessary  mime types like this `view.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/svg+xml,application/pdf'`.